# Matching negative and non-negative numbers in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl script that matches lines that start with (alphanumeric or underscore), followed by any number of spaces, followed by another (alphanumeric or underscore). I realize now that I need to also include, for the second (alphanumeric or underscore), a possibility that this could be a negative number (for instance -50). How can I accomplish this?

Original code:

```
if ( /^\w[\s]+\w/ and not /^A pdb file/ ) {
...doSomething
}
```

Unsuccessfully tried things like:

```
if ( /^\w[\s]+\-*w/ and not /^A pdb file/ )
if ( /^\w[\s]+\-{0,1}w/ and not /^A pdb file/ )
if ( /^\w[\s]+\w|-\w/ and not /^A pdb file/ )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to post also sample input and desired results?

Comment: Weird that the first 2 doesn't work; FWIW you don't need to escape the `-` since it does nothing special outside a character class.

Comment: @thb: Thanks, I would, but it is working now :o). DoubleDown: Oh right, thank you, I will remember that!

Comment: @doubleDown: The reason they don't work is that they're missing a backslash before the second `w` (that is, they have `w` instead of `\w`). (Or, put another way: the `-*` and `-{0,1}` were inserted between the `\ ` and the `w`, but should have been inserted before the `\w`.)

Comment: @ruakh, well spotted. You should post it as an answer. (I noticed the unnecessarily escaped `-` but I didn't realize that it was actually a misplaced backslash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet your needs?

```
/^\w+\s*-?\w+$/
```

It says match:

- `\w+`: any number of alphanumeric characters (including underscore)
- `\s*`: any number of spaces (if you need atleast one space, use `\s+`)
- `-?`: optional dash
- `\w+`: any number of alphanumeric characters (including underscore).  If this set of characters can only be numbers, then use `\d+` instead.

Comment: +1. Technically I'm not sure this exactly matches the OP's specifications (since it would match e.g. `12 -bar`, even though `-bar` is not "a negative number"), but it seems to be the best fix that preserves the OP's current approach.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
m{
    \A         # start of the string
    \w         # a single alphanumeric or underscore
    \s+        # one or more white space
    (?:        # non-capturing grouping
        \-     # a minus sign
        \d+    # one or more digits
    )?         # match entire group zero or one time
    \w         # a single alphanumeric or underscore
}msx;
```